# URL Anchor - space and french characters permitted?

Tags: php, html, localization

I'm building my first multilingual site (english/french)
I have to build anchor tag at some point for direct access
Here is an working example : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d6flq8dqrr2rwe/anchorTag.png

**My question is** : Is it ok to put white space and french characters after the # in the URL?

I'm asking because for now it seems to work on Chrome/Firefox/IE (latest version) and i'm wondering why I've read that they should be encoded, etc. I would like to keep the space and french characters if it's possible (more user-friendly to read the URL not encoded).

P.S:
My site is in php(code igniter) and I don't mind letting outdated browser out..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not well defined in the specs. However, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) gives the following regex for URLs:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

(.*) for the anchor would imply it'll be fine, but of course, we can test it.

A [markdown link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185279/url-anchor-space-and-french-characters-permitted#di%CC%80obhairt) doesn't appear to work on SO at least. Neither does this [anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185279/url-anchor-space-and-french-characters-permitted#di%CC%80obhairt). (Check out the source)

If I copy paste the url

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185279/url-anchor-space-and-french-characters-permitted#dìobhairt
```

into the browser, Chrome's console gives me the correct answer for window.location.hash. But it's probably best to avoid, because your users might have trouble linking to your site!

You should probably just set up a table linking "code names" to your pages, rather than using the actual page title in the URL. But do remember - URLs are for humans, so make it meaningful!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I will add a "anchor name" like you sugested, I was just being lazy and using the same has the page title for the anchor. I'll now hard-code 2 different string (one for the title, one for the anchor) :
$lang['label_video_set_up']   = "Configurer votre mat&eacute;riel";
$lang['anchor_video_set_up']   = 'configurer-votre-materiel';